# Proof: Deterministic Ito Integral (Thomas Mikosh Chapter 2)

Tags: stochastic-calculus, itos-lemma, self-study

I'm referencing *Elementary Stochastic Calculus with Finance in View* by Thomas Mikosch between chapters of Shreve's Volume II text. In one section Mikoshch text makes the following claim without proof:

Let ${f_n(t)}$ be a piecewise deterministic function of ${0\leq t\leq 1}$ such that:
$${f_n(t) = \begin{cases} 
\frac{i-1}{n}, \frac{i-1}{n} \leq t \leq \frac{i}{n} \end{cases} \text{for $1 \leq i \leq n$ }}$$

The text claims ${\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int_0^t f_n(s)\ dB_s(\omega) = \int_0^t lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_n(s)\ dB_s(\omega)=\int_0^ts\ dB_s(\omega)}$, where ${B_s(\omega)}$ is a Brownian sample path function, so the right most expression is a Riemann-Stieltjes integral which certainly converges since ${f(s)=s}$ has bounded first order variation on ${[0,1]}$.

But, how do we know the limit can be moved inside the integral? I am thinking it has to do with Monotone Convergence because ${f_n(t) \leq f_{n+1}(t)}$, but there are there are little intersections where ${f_n(t) > f_{n+1}(t)}$ for example ${f_2 > f_3}$ when ${t\in[1/3, 1/2]}$. Does the Monotone Convergence Theorem still work here?

Comment: The right most expression is an Ito-integral and *not* a RS-integral because $B$ is a Brownian motion for which the RS-integral is undefined. In the RS-integral the integrator has to have bounded variation, not the integrand. Regarding your other question: Ito integrals are first defined for step-functions as finite sums. $f_n$ is such a function. For general functions $f$ one takes an approximating sequence of step functions. Obviously, in your case $f_n\to f$ where $f(s)=s\,.$

Comment: So this just notation? Or is it relying on some rule like lim(sum) = sum(lim)?

Comment: Just notation sounds a bit oversimplified. If you really want to know why we can interchange limit and integral and if your text does not explain it then I recommend to study patiently one of the many introductions of the Ito-integral.